# Get keys from a Mifare Mini 0.3K

Tags: mifare, lib-nfc

I am playing around with a Mifare MINI 0.3K tag and a PN532 module connected with an FTDI cable via UART to Ubuntu.

I successfully managed to get the PN532 working with libnfc and mfoc/mfcuk.

But I am having issues with this Mifare MINI 0.3K Tag:

```
Found Mifare Classic Mini tag
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
* UID size: single
* bit frame anticollision supported
       UID (NFCID1): ee  6a  7e  50  
      SAK (SEL_RES): 09  
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 18092

Fingerprinting based on MIFARE type Identification Procedure:
* MIFARE Mini 0.3K
* SmartMX with MIFARE 1K emulation
```

Using mfoc (knowing that the card has at least one known default key):

```
Try to authenticate to all sectors with default keys...
Symbols: '.' no key found, '/' A key found, '\' B key found, 'x' both keys found
[Key: ffffffffffff] -> [.....]
[Key: a0a1a2a3a4a5] -> [/////]
[Key: d3f7d3f7d3f7] -> [/////]
[Key: 000000000000] -> [/////]
[Key: b0b1b2b3b4b5] -> [x////]
[Key: 4d3a99c351dd] -> [x////]
[Key: 1a982c7e459a] -> [x////]
[Key: aabbccddeeff] -> [x////]
[Key: 714c5c886e97] -> [x////]
[Key: 587ee5f9350f] -> [x////]
[Key: a0478cc39091] -> [x////]
[Key: 533cb6c723f6] -> [x////]
[Key: 8fd0a4f256e9] -> [x////]

Sector 00 - Found   Key A: a0a1a2a3a4a5 Found   Key B: b0b1b2b3b4b5
Sector 01 - Found   Key A: a0a1a2a3a4a5 Unknown Key B
Sector 02 - Found   Key A: a0a1a2a3a4a5 Unknown Key B
Sector 03 - Found   Key A: a0a1a2a3a4a5 Unknown Key B
Sector 04 - Found   Key A: a0a1a2a3a4a5 Unknown Key B  

Using sector 00 as an exploit sector
Card is not vulnerable to nested attack
```

Using `mfcuk -C -R -1:z -v 3`:

```
mfcuk - 0.3.8
Mifare Classic DarkSide Key Recovery Tool - 0.3
by Andrei Costin, zveriu@gmail.com, http://andreicostin.com

INFO: Connected to NFC reader: pn532_uart:/dev/ttyUSB0

VERIFY: 
    Key A sectors: 0
```

I would like to know how I may proceed.

Comment: What's your actual question? mfoc already clearly told you that the card is **not** vulnerable to the nested attack.

Comment: @MichaelRoland My actual question is if there is another alternative method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

same problem
https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfoc-hardnested
worked

```
git clone https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfoc-hardnested.git
autoreconf -vis
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

```
mfcuk --help
```